# issue when adding an item to a many to many relationship .net core

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, many-to-many, savechanges

i have a course management app and i have an issue when i try to add a student to a course studentsList.
when save changes run the student list changes from a list which contains old elements+ the new element to a list with only the new element (the last student added) and then saves it to database.

using EntityFramework 5.0.0

relationship declaration and seeding in context OnModelCreating()

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().HasMany<Student>(c => c.StudentsList).WithMany(s => s.Courses).UsingEntity(t => t.HasData(
            new { CoursesCourseId = Convert.ToInt64(1), StudentsListStudentId="id1"},
            new { CoursesCourseId = Convert.ToInt64(1), StudentsListStudentId="id2"},
            new { CoursesCourseId = Convert.ToInt64(1), StudentsListStudentId="id3"}   
            ));
```

models

```
public class Course
{
    public long CourseId { get; set; }

    public string CourseName { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Lesson> LessonsList { get; set; }

    public DateTime CourseStartDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime CourseEndDate { get; set; }

    public List<Student> StudentsList { get; set; }

public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public string StudentId { get; set; }

    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }

}
```

controller action

```
[HttpPatch("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterStudentToCourse(long id, [FromBody] List<string> studentsIds)
    {
        Course course = await _courseRepo.GetCourse(id);
        if (course == null || !studentsIds.Any())
            return BadRequest();
        IEnumerable<Lesson> list = await _lessonRepo.GetLessons(id);
        List<Lesson> lessonsList = list.ToList();
        List<Student> studentsList = course.StudentsList.ToList();

        foreach (string studentId in studentsIds)
        {
            Student student = _studetRepo.GetStudent(studentId);
            if (student == null)
                return BadRequest();
            if (studentsList.Contains(student))
                continue;
            
            //HERE IS THE CALL TO THE REPOSITORY ADDSTUDENT
            await _courseRepo.AddStudent(id, studentId);
            foreach (Lesson l in lessonsList)
            {
                Attendance attendance = await _attendanceRepo.CreateAttandance(studentId);
                await _lessonRepo.AddAttendance(l.LessonId, attendance);
            }
        }
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }
```

repository function

```
public async Task<bool> AddStudent(long id, string studentId)
    {
        Course course = await _context.Courses.Include(c => c.StudentsList).FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.CourseId == id);
        Student student = await _context.Students.FirstOrDefaultAsync(s => s.StudentId == studentId);
        if (course == null || student==null)
            return false;
        course.StudentsList.Add(student);

        
        return await _context.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
    }
```

Comment: First try to improve your code by making it much shorter and a lot more efficient: get one list of all students represented by `studentsIds` in only one query. Then use `course.StudentsList.AddRange(thisListOfStudents)` and save changes. That's all you need.

Comment: Maybe you can refer to the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/related-data) about Saving related data.

Comment: i did just as they do on the official docs it didnt work